# Dash Plotly multiple y Axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have the following Dataframe:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgrXl.png)

I want to plot it into a bar chart. With 3 bars, 1 for Positive, 1 for Neutral and 1 for Negative.
Im trying this:

```
fig = px.bar(senti_df, x=senti_df.index, y=['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'])
fig.show()
```

But all I get as a result is this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwgnP.png)

How can I plot them side by side? And is there a possibility to plot it into a pie chart? Thank you so much for your help, I'm a beginner :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to use raw-like data, therefore, we have some transformation via `melt()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Positive':[17], 'Neutral':[26], 'Negative':[7], 'Währung':['Bitcoin(BTC)']})
df2 = df.melt(value_vars=['Positive','Neutral','Negative'], id_vars=['Währung'], var_name='connotation')

print(df2)
```

```
        Währung connotation  value
0  Bitcoin(BTC)    Positive     17
1  Bitcoin(BTC)     Neutral     26
2  Bitcoin(BTC)    Negative      7
```

Plot bar chart

```
fig_bar = px.bar(df2, x='Währung', y='value', color='connotation', barmode='group')
fig_bar.show()
```

[image]

Plot pie chart

```
fig_pie = px.pie(df2, values='value', names='connotation')
fig_pie.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. I'll upvote as soon as I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the parameter `barmode='group'`:

```
fig = px.bar(senti_df, x='Währung', y=['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'],  barmode='group')
```

Output:

[image]

[Documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar#plotly-express-bar)

> **barmode** *(str (default 'relative'))* – One of 'group', 'overlay' or
> 'relative' In 'relative' mode, bars are stacked above zero for
> positive values and below zero for negative values. In 'overlay' mode,
> bars are drawn on top of one another. In 'group' mode, bars are placed
> beside each other.